# use jQuery Tabs to dynamically load component generated by another view in Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm developing this app and I'm struggling with a problem.

Basically I have Tabs and each Tab contains a Chart that can be dynamically generated by user input (e.g. user type something in the input field and it plots the requested data). The user input is submitted via a Form like

```
<form method="POST" id="myform">
    <p><input id="text"></p>
    <button name="test">test</button>
</form>
```

The chart is generated by a file called `chart.html` with passed-in data input. So i've included a line in the `main.html` like 
    `{% include 'chart.html' with datainput=datainput %}`

I've created a view `getdata` to generate the datainput

```
def view1(request):
    # do something
    return data_object
```

Also in a view called `main` i have

```
def main(request):
    data = view1(request)
    return render(request,'main.html',data)
```

The problem is the page always gets reloaded and the chart always goes into the first tab instead of the current one. I know that I might should use things like `ajax` but I'm having a hard time to put these techniques in one piece since I'm still a newbie. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Maybe you should post your code related to jQuery Tabs.

Comment: I'm using the standard jQuery UI tab